# Is it possible for land to be split up by climate?

Tags: internal-consistency, environment, climate

Is it possible for a continent to be slit up by climate? For example, one part is desert, another is rainforest and another one is a savanna. I got this idea from an author I've read who split her world by climates.

These are all the climates:
Tropical/Rainforest,
Hot/Desert,
Hot/Savanna,
Cold/Arctic,
Volcanic,
Water/Marine

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: You mean like Africa? There are great deserts, savannahs, and rainforests. Or like Asia, which in addition has tundra and taiga?

Comment: I frankly don't understand this question. Do you mean is it possible for climate to be the cause of separating a land mass into two or more landmasses? Or are you asking if it's possible for your world to have only six major landmasses and each landmass has a single, homogeneous climate that's different from the others?

Comment: Yes. not only possible, but almost inevitable. The **only** continent that is not split into 3 or more distinct climate zone is Antarctica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

See any continent (but Antarctica) on Earth:

[image: Climate map of Earth]

Answer (score 0):

Look at Asia, moving North from the southern tip of India: you have tropical climate, high mountain environment on the Himalaya and then the Gobi desert and from there taiga and steppe.

Totally possible.